Does Apple DepthPro model reach AGI level
I have played around with StyleGAN and now recently familiarized myself with Apple DepthPro. Now, DepthPro models a 2D frame input to 3rd dimension for the input image i.e generates the depth information map.
But what is this depth information AI based generation called; is it modeling, generating or even perhaps "figuring out"? Also it surely does it better than I could never achieve.
For reference this YouTube video I made https://youtu.be/3TdwTyOnRv4 and am still struggling with the idea what my part, making this all visible the way I want, is.
But truthfully I've yet to decide is the video mentioned above AI generated or not too.

What you're describing falls under the concept of depth map as a subset of computer vision.

In 3D computer graphics and computer vision, a depth map is an image or image channel that contains information relating to the distance of the surfaces of scene objects from a viewpoint. The term is related (and may be analogous) to depth buffer, Z-buffer, Z-buffering, and Z-depth.

The AI task here is called Monocular depth estimation. Here's an example Keras code you can run.

Depth estimation is a crucial step towards inferring scene geometry from 2D images. The goal in monocular depth estimation is to predict the depth value of each pixel or inferring depth information, given only a single RGB image as input. This example will show an approach to build a depth estimation model with a convnet and simple loss functions.

Since it's apparently a specialized application, it's not general in the sense of AGI.

Artificial general intelligence (AGI) is a type of artificial intelligence (AI) that matches or surpasses human cognitive capabilities across a wide range of cognitive tasks. This contrasts with narrow AI, which is limited to specific tasks... The timeline for achieving AGI remains a subject of ongoing debate among researchers and experts. As of 2023, some argue that it may be possible in years or decades; others maintain it might take a century or longer; and a minority believe it may never be achieved.


I like the tone of this answer - you are hired.
